# MySQL Pivot Table get first and last rows within grouping records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have banking database written on mysql. I'm Using MySQL pivot table for generation group wise records / reports.

This is my sample table for account maintenance,

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
account_number   | description   | Transaction Amount | Balance  | transaction_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1021212              1             0                    0          2013-04-02
1021213              1             100                 100         2013-04-01
1021212              1             1000                1000        2013-04-02
1021213              1             100                 200         2013-04-01
1021214              1             500                 500         2013-04-02
1021212              2             100                 900         2013-04-09
```

I need to run full report with displays daily (monthly) transactions.

This is my required report format,

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
account_number   | init_balance   | total_banking | total_withdraw | final_balance
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1021212              0               1000            100                900
1021213              100             100             0                  200
1021214              0             500             0                    600
```

I'm trying to generate this report with pivot table query and I could get all information except initial and final balance fields.

This is my sample query,

```
SELECT account_number,
**xxxxxxxxxx AS init_balance,**
SUM(CASE WHEN m.description = '1' THEN m.amount END) AS total_banking,
SUM(CASE WHEN m.description = '2' THEN m.amount END) AS total_withdraw,
**xxxxxxxxxx AS final_balance**
FROM account
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
GROUP BY account_number
ORDER BY account_number
```

if Anyone can help, Kindly let me know the pattern of writing pivot table for get first and last row of the table withing grouping results.

Comment: I haven't understood what do you really want. Where do you get init_balance? What tables do you have and what tables do you need?

Comment: Try this but not match for both sides,

CASE WHEN MIN(id) THEN m.balance END AS init,

Comment: Dear Michael Sivolobov,

I need to get first the balance of first row as initial balance and last row of the same account as final balance..

Comment: I don't see any balance field in your example table. I only see transaction amount and I don't understand why account 1021212 has init_balance = 0 but account 1021213 has init_balance = 100

Comment: Dear Michael Sivolobov,

However I need to first record as init balance and last record as final balanace.

Comment: Do you have autoincremented id field in your table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28664/discussion-between-michael-sivolobov-and-sathiska)

Comment: yes..

Auto increment column name is id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like that:

```
    SELECT
    m.account_number,
    SUM(IF(id = t.min_id, balance, 0)) AS init_balance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.description = '1' THEN m.amount END) AS total_banking,
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.description = '2' THEN m.amount END) AS total_withdraw,
    SUM(IF(id = t.max_id, balance, 0)) AS final_balance
FROM
    account m
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            account_number,
            MIN(id) AS min_id,
            MAX(id) AS max_id
        FROM
            account
        GROUP BY account_number
    ) AS t
ON
    m.account_number = t.account_number
WHERE
    transaction_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
GROUP BY
    account_number
ORDER BY
    account_number
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. This is the correct answer I need. I'll apply this in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CASE WHEN MIN(record_id_field) THEN Balance   END AS initial_amount
```

AND

```
CASE WHEN MAX(record_id_field) THEN Balance   END AS final_amount
```